# If I have multiple questions over same subject, should I break it to multiple posts?

Tags: discussion

I have a topic where I have multiple, more and less detailed/related questions I would like to have an answer. Traditionally doing multiple posts in any forum would be considered spamming, but I am not sure what is SO approach.

The reasons why I would like to break my question cluster to smaller pieces are following:

- Easier to have appealing question on subject line when not trying to get everything under the same 'roof'
- Easier to find for people who are researching the same subject
- Faster to read and easier to answer

So, is it considered to be a bad habit to ask multiple (and, of course, different) questions over the same subject?

Comment: If they are different questions with separate answers then you certainly should make multiple posts. Just make sure they adhere to the standards and that you have researched and tried yourself first, of course. I would do one at a time because if they are related then one answer may lead you to be able to answer some of the others yourself.

Comment: We generally have a one question per question policy.  There is a little leeway for things like highly related follow ups or asking if something is this way or that way.